# Removing leading zeros from number PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to remove the leading 0's from a number in PHP. The problem is that I'm able to do that in every number, but when I reach the number 09, the conversion done is incorrect. It gives me 0, instead of 9.

I've tried every solution that I could find on the web, and every single one fails with the number 9.

Right now the code that I have is this:

```
function removezeros($value)
{
    switch ($value){
        case 01: return 1;
        case 02: return 2;
        case 03: return 3;
        case 04: return 4;
        case 05: return 5;
        case 06: return 6;
        case 07: return 7;
        case 08: return 8;
        case 09: return 9;
    }
    return $value;
}


$month =  09;
echo  removezeros($month);
```

I also tried defining the number as integer like this:

```
$month = (int)$month;
```

and returning the int value with this code `$month=intval($month)`, and still nothing.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: `09` is seen as an octal number and 9 is an invalid octal number, so it gets converted to 0.

Comment: hmm I see, but by saying that 09 is a integer, with  $month =(int) 09, shouldn't it solve the problem?

Comment: No, if you have 09 in your source code you have an invalid octal number in there and it will get [silently converted to 0](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) or throw an error in PHP 7.

Comment: Can you not address the problem at the source and supply valid integers/

Comment: I wrote an answer, but I deleted it because I suspect OP is downvoting, and we're going in circles around the central problem: where `$month` is coming from.  If it's user input, we're looking at a string, and `ltrim` will do it.  If it's not -- where did it come from, and why not just write it without the octal format?

Comment: @WillBriggs ... this $month comes from a string explode. The problem is that I was trying to use the month chuck from that string to use in a mktime function. Having the 0 preceding the 9 in the month value, made that function return the wrong value, so I was trying to figure out a solution that I could use, since doing intvalue($data_string_bits[1]) was not working. But I figured out another way to do it now. I didn't knew that having a 0 before the 9 was interpreted as an octal. There should be a way to declare it as an int, even if it has a 0 before the 9 .

Comment: it comes from a string explode - means it is a string. so to solve the problem, you have to fix the string first and then cast it to integer!

Comment: Mr. Dahmen here has your answer, then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you provide a value in octal notation, you can cast it first into a string to simply trim the leading zero.
`ltrim` will cast any number into a string before trimming:

```
$month = ltrim($month, '0'); // string
```

Or:

```
$month = intval(ltrim($month, '0')); // integer
```

Comment: First: Not true - numbers get convertet into strings when a function expects a string. Second: `09` is not an integer itself - that would be `9`. See the above comment about the octal number. See the edit above to grt an integer value.

Comment: Why the downvote? It has to be treated as a string to avoid a conversion error - like you are experiencing! Also the first answer is correct in that sense.

Comment: your comment says it doesn't work for strings. but you provide a string. so i don't see the probleme here.